# MarkLogic REST PUT to add document returns 500 internal server error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Has anyone gotten the 500 internal server error when inserting an XML doc to MarkLogic (HTTP REST PUT)

Code:

```
    static public bool InsertXmlDocument(string uri, string data, string databaseName = "Documents")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
        {
            return false;
        }

        WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");

        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        client.UploadString(new Uri($"http://localhost:8002/LATEST/documents?database={databaseName}&uri={uri}" ), "PUT",  data );

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the full error message, the value of the expanded URL in the UploadString (to validate well formed URL) and a snippet of the data.   Also look into the server error and application logs for any events at that time.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using port 8002. That's the REST Management API port, for administrative operations. For the Client APIs, you need a REST API instance. One comes pre-installed on port 8000, or you can create your own following the instructions here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021

Also, if you're using the REST Client API from Java, you should probably consider using the Java Client API instead, which is a Java layer on top of the REST Client API. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the server ErrorLog.txt but it doesnt have any error info. The URL is valid because I can insert documents with different XML.

It turns out, if you have any unescaped items in your XML values (quotes, ampersands, etc) then MarkLogic gives a 500 internal server error.

Thats really lame in my book, they should return an error saying invalid XML.

In my case, I had one single quote in some text within 5000 lines of XML. Really annoying to hunt this down

Comment: MarkLogic would only trip over invalid utf-8 chars, unescaped less-than and ampersand signs, and unknown named entities. It should not trip over single quotes, unless you are not talking about `apos` but referring to unicode chars like left and right quotes. Are you sure it was a single quote that was the culprit?

Comment: I do agree that a 500 is less elegant. I can create an internal ticket if you have a small example you can share..